# local base for the product topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $\Lambda$ be a nonempty set and  $\prod_{\alpha \in \Lambda}\mathbb{R}=\mathbb{R}^\Lambda$. Given $f\in \mathbb{R}^\Lambda$ prove that the family $B_f=\lbrace \lbrace g\in \mathbb{R}^\Lambda : |g(\alpha)-f(\alpha)|<M\   \forall \alpha \in L\rbrace : M>0, L\subset \Lambda \text{ finite}\rbrace $ is a local base at $f$ for the product topology on $\mathbb{R}^\Lambda$.

Attempt: Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^\Lambda$ be an open set and $f\in U$. We want to show the existance of $B \in B_f$ such that $f\in B \subset U$. $\lbrace g\in \mathbb{R}^\Lambda : |g(\alpha)-f(\alpha)|<M\   \forall \alpha \in L\rbrace = \bigcap_{i=1}^k\Pi_{\alpha_k}^{-1}(\Pi_{\alpha_k}(f)-M,\Pi_{\alpha_k}(f)+M))$, where $\Pi_{\alpha_k}$ is the projection map from $\mathbb{R}^\Lambda$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Since $\Pi_{\alpha_k}$ is continous map then the inverse image of open set is open. Thus $\lbrace g\in \mathbb{R}^\Lambda : |g(\alpha)-f(\alpha)|<M\   \forall \alpha \in L\rbrace$ is open in $ \mathbb{R}^\Lambda$. Does this show the existence of $B \in B_f$ such that $f\in B \subset U$?

Comment: The proof is correct but I would mention how you found the finite set $L \subseteq \Lambda$ (and/or the $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_k$) and $M > 0$ within $B = \lbrace g\in \mathbb{R}^\Lambda : |g(\alpha)-f(\alpha)|<M\   \forall \alpha \in L\rbrace$